# Pandas Boolean selection updated?

Tags: pandas, indexing, boolean

I was used to getting a single number, which told me how many cases are TRUE for either for the conditions in the code. However, since I used `conda update all` I now get a list of values with either 0 or 1. I wonder what is now the simplest method in pandas to get this task done. I guess that this is a pandas update. I did a google search but could not find that they changed boolean indexing. What is the easiest way to get this sum of booleans (I know how to get it but I cannot imagine that this extra step is required).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randint(10,size=10)
y = np.random.randint(10,size=10)
d ={}
d['x'] = x
d['y'] = y
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
sum([df['x']>=6] or [df['y']<=3])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use vectorized or `|`:

```
(df.x.ge(6) | df.y.le(3)).sum()
# 9
```

Or: `((df.y <= 3) | (df.x >= 6)).sum()`, `sum((df.y <= 3) | (df.x >= 6))`.